# TinyMCE: Reverse the <p> and <br>

Tags: javascript, tinymce

When I type into TinyMCE shift＋enter for `<br>` and enter for `<p>` is the default setup but how do I reverse this?

I want `enter` as `<br>`

`shift＋enter` as `<p>`

I know `forced_root_block: ''`would change this but I need the `<p>` element inserted before I do any typing. So disabling the `<p>` block is not an option.

Comment: Which version of tinyMCE are you using?

Comment: @showdev I am on version 3 "majorVersion : '3',
minorVersion : '5.5',

  releaseDate : '2012-07-19',

Answer (score 2):

You can use this option to force br for new lines

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    force_br_newlines : true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What about [`forced_root_block`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:forced_root_block)?

If you set it to `false` or `""`, BR is the default and `SHIFT+ENTER` will produce a P. [As seen on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/qod4pmoo/)

I read that on there after googling for 2 minutes.

Comment: yes it does but the issue is the html output doesn't get wrapped by <p>